# Checking if word exists in Ocaml StringMap

Tags: ocaml, word-count

I am new to OCaml and am trying to create a wordcount from a list of words. For each word, I am trying to do this:

```
let check x  = if StringMap.mem x then y = StringMap.find x testMap (* I want to add one to this value *) 
else
let testMap = StringMap.add x 1 testMap ;;
```

Apart from getting errors in this code, I am pretty sure I have got the logic a little bit wrong as well. I am new to functional programming so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

`StringMap.add` is a new map; the original map is untouched.

To make progress, you need to keep track of the current value of the map.

One possibility for `check` is

```
let check : string -> StringMap.t -> StringMap.t 
= fun string map ->
  if StringMap.mem string map
  then let y = StringMap.find string map in
  (* do something with y *) 
  else (* add a binding between string and 1 *)
```

where you need to complete the two commented parts.